# Google Photos collection Slider in JavaScript / Angular / React / Vue?

Tags: javascript, npm, slider, uislider, syncfusion

I am looking forward to creating a verticle photo slider in my Angular / React app just like we see in the Google Photos Web version. Here is the screenshot attached in case you have not seen it yet on https://photos.google.com/ of your google account[image]

The slider is divided into the yearly category where small dots represents months. It is smart enough to create dots based on photos that you have in particular months.

If you click on any dots or year, your main photos section will move based on the selection.

If you scroll through your photos using a Mouse wheel or mouse pad, this slider will change position based on your scroll photo area.

I tried to find any open source NPM library that I could check but I did not yet. Any help that I can get on how to build this in Pure JavaScript or in TypeScript, I would be damn glad.

Any thoughts, let's discuss them in the comments.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements have been validated in both the Slider and Linear Gauge components. But currently, we do not have support to render the Slider component with irregular label intervals as shown in your screenshot. This requirement is also not possible with the Linear Gauge. Also, we don’t have direct support to include photos as maintained in the Google photos in Slider component. Please check the available layout of both Slider and Linear Gauge components from the below link.

Linear Gauge: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/bootstrap5/linear-gauge/default

Slider: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/bootstrap5/slider/default.html